# How do I unenroll from a course on Bb CourseSites?

Tags: coursera

I enrolled to a course long ago, that's taught on [Bb CourseSites](http://www.coursesites.com), is there a way to unenroll from a course?

Comment: @SathajithBhat, the coursera tag is wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://coursesites.edusupportcenter.com/sims/helpcenter/common/layout/SelfhelpArticleView.seam?inst_name=coursesites&article_id=8619-8308-214&cid=30285) link states:

> Organization enrollments are managed by the institution and the
>   organization leader. If enabled, you may self enroll. Contact the
>   organization leader or institution about enrollment. After you are
>   enrolled, only the leader or an administrator can unenroll you.

I'm not sure if it applies to all types of course but in my case I believe this is the answer.